# boost msm cannot processing polymorphic event?

Tags: c++, boost, boost-msm

I am using boost:msm to create a state machine. It seems when processing events, the state machine does not care about polymorphism.

Say I have multiple events all derived from a base event:

```c
struct EvtBase { virtual ~EvtBase();}

struct EvtA : EvtBase {};
struct EvtB : EvtBase {};
```

Then if I have a bunch of events stored in a vector via pointers of base event type:

```c
typedef std::shared_ptr<EvtBase> ptrEvt;
std::vector<ptrEvt> event_list {std::make_shared<EvtA>(), std::make_shared<EvtB>()};
```

When I process these events by the state machine:

```cpp
for (const auto& pEvt: event_list) {
    fsm.process_event(*pEvt);
}
```

The boost::msm state machine thinks it receives `EvtBase`, rather than the actual event pointed by the pointer.

Am I doing something wrong, or is there a way to change this behavior and make `process_event` respect polymorphism?

Comment: runtime polymorphism and compile time one don't mix together very well. I think you should consider std::variant instead

Comment: @AlessandroTeruzzi Good suggestion but unfortunately I can't use c++17.

Comment: you can use boost::variant instead

Comment: @AlessandroTeruzzi Good call, that does work.

Answer (score 1):

As suggested by @Alessandro Teruzzi using `boost::variant` (due to lack of c++17), this is what I did:

```cpp
#include "boost/variant.hpp"

// A typedef of boost::variant, put all event here
typedef boost::variant<EvtA, EvtB, EvtC> EvtType;

// This is the static visitor functor, I use it to store a pointer to fsm as 
// well because I don't know how to make operator() take a second parameter
template <class FSM>
class ProcessEvent : boost::static_visitor<> {
public:
  ProcessEvent(FSM* pfsm) : pFsm(pfsm) {}  // used to pass in pointer to fsm

  template <class Event>
  void operator()(Event& evt) const {
    pFsm->process_event(evt);
  }

private:
  FSM* pFsm;
} // ProcessEvent

// This is the function I actually call
template <class FSM>
void fsm_process_event(FSM& fsm, EvtType v) {
  ProcessEvent<FSM> fsm_process_event(&fsm);
  boost::apply_visitor(fsm_process_event, v);
}
```

So when I have a vector of event, I can do:

```cpp
for (const auto& evt: EventList) {
  fsm_process_event(some_fsm, evt);
}
```

and I verified that the state machine do work properly.

Comment: +1 for answering your own question; I'd suggest with c++14 (and recent enough Boost) you can simplify a lot: https://pastebin.ubuntu.com/p/w8drD8stMJ/

Comment: @sehe good suggestion! I thought I have to use a functor that inherits from `boost:static_visitor` as a visitor, but apparently Lambda works too!